# Create unique ID for HttpServletRequest from mobile

Tags: java, session, jsessionid

When using the default web browser in some mobile devices, the session ID is renewed for each request.

So when using:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.getId();
```

The ID is different for different requests from the same device.

It happens only on Android device that do not use Chrome.
Is there a way to create different unique ID that does not use the session?

Comment: You do want to maintain a session with the same session ID? And some other browsers throw away the prior session ID?

Comment: Yes, some browsers sends the next request with different ID.